# Which array among 3 arrays contain a specific value and then use that array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 3 arrays:

```
northamerica = ["USA","Canada","Mexico"];
europe = ["France", "Germany", "Italy"];
africa = ["Morocco", "Ghana", "Madagascar"];
```

I want to find which one of these 3 arrays contain a specific value. It should look like this: 
**Input**:

```
Madagascar
```

**Output**:

```
The countries in the same continent are: Morocco, Ghana, Madagascar
```

How can I get this result with Javascript?

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Cool, good luck! On a serious note, your question is unclear. What's your question?

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  We can't help if we don't know what we're helping with.

Comment: I am sorry, I just  updated it. the question is: how can I obtain this result with Javascript, given the input and the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do as follows;

```js
function getContinentNeighbours(country){
  return country +
         " is in the same continent with: " +
         continents.reduce((p,continent) => continent.includes(country) ? p += continent.filter(f => f !== country)
                                                                                        .reduce((f,s) => f + ", " + s)
                                                                        : p ,"");
}
var northamerica = ["USA","Canada","Mexico"],
          europe = ["France", "Germany", "Italy"],
          africa = ["Morocco", "Ghana", "Madagascar"],
      continents = [northamerica, europe, africa];

console.log(getContinentNeighbours("Mexico"));
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly  what I was looking for

Comment: @Randriakotonjanahary Tolotra S You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
europe.includes("Madagascar") // false
northamerica.includes("Madagascar") // false
africa.includes("Madagascar") // true
```

Alternatively you can use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) - this will return -1 if the element is not present in the array.

Comment: How this one answers the question?

Comment: Although worded poorly, the title of the original question seemed to me to be asking for a way to find the array that contains a specific value. Which I demonstrated in the answer

Comment: Reading the OP wants as input a country and as output the countries in the same continent. Not a Boolean value if the specific country exist in the array.